# How to create sub partitions in measure groups of SSAS OLAP

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I want to break up one of my partitions of my measure group that has 450 million rows into sub partitions to make processing and querying faster. I currently split my measure group using attr1 of dimension1. Is it possible to split each partition further based on a different attr2 of the same dimension? I know that I can write a SQL query to do this but what I want to know is how to create the slice hint such that SSAS knows to look at the sub partitions.
I tried something like this in slice expression for partition 
{dim1.Attr1&val1, dim1.Attr2&value2} but the processing failed with error saying tuple can't contain two different dimensions!?!
What can I do here? Can multiple partitions have same slice hint ? Will that solve my problem if I give same slice hint for all related partitions ?

Comment: What is a slice hint?   No hits on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified that setting the same slice property for all the related partitions solves my problem.

Here are links to what the "Slice" property of partition means

[link1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms174764.aspx&ei=VeBXVLrJOYLNoASZloB4&usg=AFQjCNHdXeQjo9uIgq-tLvn0ZMfHZ9Yh9A&sig2=1kSLMmrjM9TDUeEoU8Xq8Q&bvm=bv.78677474,d.cGE)

[link2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshabnamwatson.wordpress.com%2F2013%2F06%2F27%2Fsetting-the-slice-for-ssas-partitions%2F&ei=VeBXVLrJOYLNoASZloB4&usg=AFQjCNFQct_ryHiNkceTsTUs_NcAMxmd2A&sig2=RHdrWjy8qkehZasnSKe4FA&bvm=bv.78677474,d.cGE)